# How to create a one-to-many relationship in Hibernate just using the foreign keys

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a relationship between two Hibernate entities: `User` and `Item`.

`User`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer mId;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String mUsername;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private List<Item> mItems;
}
```

`Item`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users_item")
public class Item implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="item_id")
    private Integer mId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="item_class_id")
    private Integer mClassId;
}
```

However, when I query for a `User` all I want is a `List<Integer>` that represents their `Items'` ids *not* a `List<Item>`. Are there annotations I can use, or some other way using `Hibernate` to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there are annotations that will support that kind of requested behavior.

However, if you want to get a list of the id of items, that is easy to do in two steps which I like also to use on my own projects. The two steps are:

1. Get the List as you did it until now with hibernate
2. Use Java8-Streams to get a list of id. like this:

   ```
   User user = session.get(1,User.class);
   List<Item> list = user.getMItems();
   List<Integer> listIds = list.stream().map(item -> item.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```